# Linked list using a list

Tags: c#, list, doubly-linked-list

Would there be any problems if I did the following to imitate a liked list using a list.

Create a class like this

```
public class MyClass
{
 //some properties
 public MyClass Previous {get; set;}
 public MyClass Next {get; set;}
}
```

and add this to a generic List.

I only add elements to this list and never remove them.

I am not using the .Net LinkedList class as I had overlooked the Previous property of the LinkedListNode class. I was in a hurry to get things working.

The way I am using this class is mostly by using the ForEach extension of the List.

```
List<MyClass> MyList = new List<MyClass>();

//add some elements with Previous,Next set

MyList.Foreach(CalculateValues);

CalculateValues(MyClass current)
{
  MyClass prev = current.Previous; 
  //check for null and return etc
  //In some moethods I use Next
  current.SomeProperty += prev.SomeProperty; 
}
```

I see that the LinkedList has no ForEach method though. I could still iterate using ForEach loop.
Thanks for all the great answers.

Comment: What problems do you expect? What have you tried?

Comment: Why not using a .NET [LinkedList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7.aspx)?

Comment: Sometimes I wish I could downvote comments...

Comment: Why would you add those elements to a list? And this doesn't look like an imitation of linked list, it *is* a linked list.

Comment: Could you post a sample code showing how do you want to use this class?

Comment: @thecoop I was concerned that the circular references between elements would prevent them from being garbage collected.

Comment: .NET does not have that limitation. Circular references will not prevent objects from being collected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you would be violating the *Single Responsibility Principle* by using the same class to represent both a Collection of an item and the item itself. And you wouldn't be making use of the perfectly-good classes that come standard with the .NET library, like `LinkedList<T>`.

Answer (score 3):

You should at least include some `Item` property

```
public class MyClass<T>
{
 //some properties
 public MyClass Previous {get; set;}
 public MyClass Next {get; set;}
 public T Item {get; set;}
}
```

The I would suggest to implement `IEnumerable` too to get some iterating functionality. `IList` seems reasonable too. But why not use the Built in `LinkedList`?

Answer (score 2):

Your issue isn't with using a Generic List to store your items. It's the fact that your class is storing the Previous/Next items rather than just data about itself. You'd never be able to re-use the Linked List implementation.

You should have something to store a Node in the Linked List:

```
public class LinkedList<T>
{
    private List<LinkedListNode<T>> nodes = new List<LinkedListNode<T>>();
}

public class LinkedListNode<T>
{
    public LinkedListNode<T> Previous { get; set; }
    public LinkedListNode<T> Next { get; set; }
    public T Item { get; set; }
}

public class MyClass
{
    // Some Properties
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `public LinkedListNode Previous/next` instead of `T`?

Comment: @Skalli - Yes it should. Fixed.